# Autofill state and city from zipcode using api in react js

Tags: reactjs, api, validation, redux, react-redux

I am adding validation of zip code. If you enter a zipcode, an API for validity is called and state and city should be set as per the response from API response. The API response is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "city": "SAN FRANCISCO",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "94103"
    }
}
```

I am calling this API like:

```
export const zipValidation = (data, callback) => (dispatch) => {
return dispatch(
    apiCallBegan({
      url: zipUrl,
      data,
      callback,
      method: "POST",
    })
  );
};
```

I made an function to call the API and store the response:

```
zipCallback = (res) => {
    console.log(res.data.data.city)
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const city = res.data.data.city;
      const state = res.data.data.state;
    }
  }
```

But I am unable to get the logic on how t set this field in my react js input form.

```
<div>
                <div>
                  {this.renderInput("zip", "Zip")}
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div>
                <div>
                  {this.renderInput("city", "City", )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<div>
                <div>
                  {this.renderInput("state", "State", )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share a copy of the component with the input field?

Comment: @Claeusdev I have edited my question. Please help if possible

Comment: Is your redux store setup with middleware so that it executes the call and stores the data in redux?  If so, you would use a selector to select the info from the redux state.  Otherwise, you need to save the city and state to your component state.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I tried doing that but the input field values are not getting updated: 
  zipCallback = (res) => {
    console.log(res.data.data.city)
    console.log(this.state.data.city)

    if (res.status === 200) {
      this.setState({
        [this.state.data.city]: res.data.data.city
      });      
      this.setState({
        [this.state.data.state]: res.data.data.state
      });
    } else {
        toast(<AlertSuccess message={"Invalid Zip code"} />);
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it :

```
 zipCallback = (res) => {

if (res.status === 200) {
  const {data, errors} = this.state;
  data.city = res.data.data.city;
  data.state = res.data.data.state;
  errors.city = "";
  errors.state = "";
  this.setState({data, errors})
} else {
    toast(<AlertError message={res.data.error.Description} />);
}
```

}